# How to prevent python script from freezing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, ubuntu-16.04

I work for a digital marketing agency having multiple clients. And in one of the projects, I have a very resource intensive python script (which fetches data for Facebook ads), to be run on all those clients (say 500+ in number) in ubuntu 16.04 server.

Originally script took around 2 mins to complete, with 300 MB RES & 1000 MB VM (as per htop), for 1 client. Hence optimized it with ThreadPoolExecutor (max_workers=10) so that script can run on 4 clients concurrently (almost).

Then found out that sometimes, script froze during run (or basically its in "comatose state"). Debugged & profiled and found that its not the script that's causing issue, but its the system.

Then batched the script, means if there are 20 input clients, ran 5 instances (4*5=20) of script. Here sometimes it went fine but sometimes last instance froze.

Then found out that RAM (2G) was being overused, hence increased swapping memory from 0 to 1G. That did the trick. But if few clients are heavy in memory, same thing happens.

Have attached the screenshot of the latest run where after running the 8 instances, last 2 froze. They can be left for days for that matter.

I am thinking of increasing the server RAM from 2G to 4G but not sure if that's the permanent solution. Did anyone has faced similar issue?

[image: First two instances of froze script]

[image: free -h output]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by `Debugged & profiled and found that its not the script that's causing issue, but its the system.`.

Comment: Sure @TomDalton, I used elimination method to rule out the cause of this freeze. Added multiple loggings, ran a mock script commenting memory intensive tasks etc to find out that it was not the script which was having code issue.

Comment: Cant you share more details about the script? It seems the script it is really heavy but with out the more details it is impossible to fix or improve anything.

Answer (score 4):

You need to fix the Ram consumption of your script,
if your script allocates more memory than your system can provide it get's memory errors, in case you have them in threadpools or similar constructs the threads may never return under some circumstances.

You can fix this by using async functions with timeouts and implementing automatic restart handlers, in case a process does not yield an expected results.

The best way to do that is heavily dependent on the script and will probably require altering already created code

The issue is definitly with your script and not with the OS.

The fastetst workaround  would be to increase she system memory or to reduce the  amount of threads.

Answer (score 2):

If just adding 1GB of swap area "almost" did the trick then definitely increasing the physical memory is a good way to go. Btw remember that swapping means you're using disk storage, whose speed is measured in millisecs, while RAM speed is measured in nanosecs - so avoiding swap guarantees a performance boost.

And then, reboot your system every now and then. Although Linux is far better than Windows in this respect, memory leaks *do* occur in Linux too, and a reboot every few months will surely help.

Comment: Hey @gimix, I was incorrect. Swap did nothing. Actually script is freezing just after updating an index in elasticsearch. Not sure why. And funny thing is, it goes fine sometimes.

Comment: Have you debugged the connection to ES? Is it responding every time - or could it be that the connection "hangs" and the script times out?

Answer (score 0):

As  Gornoka stated you need to alter the memory comsumption of the script as added details this can also be done by removing declared variables within the script once used with the keyword

```
del
```

This can also be done by  ensuring that if it is processing massive files it does this line by line and saving it as it finishes each line.

I have had this happen and it usually is an indicator of working with to much data at once within the ram and it is always better to work with it partially whenever possible and if not possible get more RAM